# Google Sheets script for custom menu item to hide/show a column if it contains a value of "Timestamp" in a row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to add a custom menu called "Timestamp" with items "Show" and "Hide" that will show a column if "Show" is selected and the column contains a value of "Timestamp" or hide a column if "Hide" is selected and column contains a value of "Timestamp". That is a text value not a result of timestamp.

I currently have the below which only shows all or hide column 11. Need it to hide or show all columns that contain a value of "Timestamp"

```
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Timestamps')
    .addItem('Show', 'showColumns')
    .addItem('Hide', 'hideColumns')
    .addToUi();
}
function showColumns() {
  sh.unhideColumn(sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()))
}
function hideColumns(){
  sh.hideColumns(11)
}
```